# How to backup MS SQL using SMO and Virtual Device

Tags: c#, backup, smo

Currently i am backing up a remote database via SMO. I am able to backup with `DeviceType.File`

I want to be able to use VirtualDevice:

```
        Backup dbBackup = new Backup();
        dbBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        dbBackup.Database = "DevTarget";

        BackupDeviceItem dbBackupItem = new BackupDeviceItem();
        dbBackupItem.DeviceType = DeviceType.VirtualDevice;
        dbBackupItem.Name = "Full_Backup_test2";

        dbBackup.Devices.Add(dbBackupItem);
```

Has anybody ever used `DeviceType.VirtualDevice` if so please help as to how to use it and its features.